# Finding the geometric center of n points on a 2D plane - Manhattan distance

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

Let's assume that we have `p` random points on a `M-by-M` grid. We want to find a point on the grid which has the lowest sum of Manhattan distances to all `p` points.

What I thought : I thought that maybe with averaging all x's and y's and trying all 9 points near to that point we may find the requested point. But it seems that this approach doesn't work :

```
static void find_center(int p , int M){
    int[][] point = new int[p][2]; // initializing p points as random
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < p ; i++){
        point[i][0] = r.nextInt(M);
        point[i][1] = r.nextInt(M);
    }
    //the naive brute force approach to find the real closest point on the grid
    int min_distance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int[] result = new int[2];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < M ; i++){
        for (int j = 0 ; j < M ; j++){
            int d = 0;
            for (int k = 0 ; k < point.length ; k++){
                d += Math.abs(i - point[k][0]);
                d += Math.abs(j - point[k][1]);
            }
            if (d < min_distance){
                min_distance = d;
                result[0] = i;
                result[1] = j;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(min_distance);
    System.out.println(result[0] + " : " + result[1]);
    //the other proposed approach
    System.out.println("---------");
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < point.length ; i++){
        x += point[i][0];
        y += point[i][1];
    }
    x /= point.length;
    y /= point.length;
    min_distance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int a : new int[] {-1,0,1}){
        for (int b : new int[] {-1,0,1}){
            int d = 0;
            for (int k = 0 ; k < point.length ; k++){
                d += Math.abs(x + a - point[k][0]);
                d += Math.abs(y + b - point[k][1]);
            }
            if (d < min_distance){
                min_distance = d;
                result[0] = x + a;
                result[1] = y + b;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(min_distance);
    System.out.println(result[0] + " : " + result[1]);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jdv-Jan de Vaan said , the following code works :

```
    Arrays.sort(point , new Comparator<int[]>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(int[] arg0, int[] arg1) {
            return Double.compare(arg0[0], arg1[0]);
        }
    });
    int median_x = point[point.length/2][0];
    Arrays.sort(point , new Comparator<int[]>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(int[] arg0, int[] arg1) {
            return Double.compare(arg0[1], arg1[1]);
        }
    });
    int median_y = point[point.length/2][1];
    int min_distance = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < point.length ; i++){
        min_distance += Math.abs(point[i][0] - median_x) + Math.abs(point[i][1] - median_y);
    }
    System.out.println(min_distance);
    System.out.println(median_x + " : " + median_y);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the point you are looking for is at the median X and median Y: The X and Y that have as much points before them -in the X and Y dimension respectively- as after them).

At that point, moving to left or right will not decrease the total distance, as there are equally many connections left as right. Same goes for up and down Y.

This is due to the somewhat peculiar definition of the manhattan distance, you can in fact calculate manhatten distance total separately in X and Y, and then add.

Edit: The median is easy to compute, just make a list of all values of X, sort it, and pick the one in the middle of the list. Same for Y.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum spanning tree can compute the shortest distance tree to all other points.

Comment: I don't think this will work, because the center is not always an existing vertex.